# in datastage, parameter of job acitivity in job and job properties parameter of that job activity are always get same parameters?

Tags: datastage

I have a question... (sorry about i'm a beginner at datastage)

[image]

[image]

First Image, show seq_1000_mas job. and in that seq_1000_mas_job, there is a seq_1100_src job(second image).

I found that parameters of seq_1100_src in seq_1000_mas_job have same parameter.
(first image and second image)

parameter of job acitivity in job and job properties parameter of that job activity
are always get same parameters?(is it automatically same?)

if not always same, and then which function should i have to see?

if it is not automatic, and then if i make a seq_1100_src job(for example), i should have to set parameter same as seq_1100_src job's paramters in seq_1100_mas job?

I'm confusing about datastage prcoess now .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

The parameter names you see in the job activity stage always match the ones provided by the referenced job. If you change the job but the parameters do not change, you don't have to worry about the job invocation activity. If you change the Parameters of the job (themselves, not their values), you might also need to change the invocation and recompile the sequence job, except if you don't pass any vaules to the job and rely on the jobs prameters defaults.